# Обновление базы данных на сервере данными полученными по почте

Tags: php, python, база-данных, email, 1с

Необходимо создать личный кабинет клиента бухгалтерской фирмы. В личном кабинете для пользователя будет доступна информация о сдаче налоговой отчетности и т.д., которая должна поступать из БД программы 1С на которой работают бухгалтеры. База с программы 1С выгружается в формате xls/csv/xml полностью и отправляется по электронной почте. Точнее сказать есть только такая возможность, так как программа 1С самописная и поддержка оставляет желать лучшего.. 
Могу ли я принимать базу данных во вложении письма на сервере и обновлять текущую базу полученными данными. Цель всего этого беспорядка, показывать на вьюхе в ЛК клиента актуальную информацию. На сколько эта конструкция жизнеспособна и эффективна? Спасибо за потраченное время)

Answer (score 0):

Сделать всё это более, чем возможно. XML можно отправлять вложенным файлом по электронной почте. 1С будет опрашивать почту для нахождения письма с таким вложением, потом скачает файл и будет уже считывать и записывать данные. Другой вопрос: зачем через электронную почту? Почему не реализовать всё веб-сервисом? Намного проще, т.к. вы УЖЕ будете в базе 1С. Или HTTP-сервисом, на крайний случай. В любом случае подумайте над транспортом данных, т.к. электронная почта не самый лучший вариант

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ! 1С находится на локальном компьютере, выгрузку с него можно отправить по электронике. Программа 1С самописная поэтому данные возможно отправить только по почте(только так умеет специалист который ее обслуживает).  В планах на сервере забирать с новых писем данные с базы 1С, которые будут в формате exe/xml/csv, и обновлять базу данных на сервере. Ну а дальше реализовать API.